# Renewing Minikube SSL certificates for 10 years

Tags: bash, kubernetes, openssl, minikube, rbac

I am trying to renew a clusters set of certificates that are stored on an ami and used to boot up a Kubernetes cluster, currently if the certs get to over a year old the cluster can not be started. Using kubeadm is not a solution due to the added start up time to the ami and therefore I am trying to have the certificates have a 10 year expiry on the ami at creation (I am not worried about the security risks to due this being an nearly air gaped training environment).

Currently I have tried this method to extend the expiry time which works, it allows minikube to start however I am still facing issues with the api server:

```bash
# Extend Certificates
extend_certificate() {
    local base_path="$1"
    local node_name="$2"
    local days=3649
    cd "$base_path"

    # Map of COMMON_NAME to "KEY_NAME:CA_CERT:CA_KEY"
    declare -A map=(
        ["front-proxy-client"]="front-proxy-client.key:front-proxy-ca.crt:front-proxy-ca.key"
        ["apiserver-etcd-client"]="apiserver-etcd-client.key:etcd/ca.crt:etcd/ca.key"
        ["apiserver-kubelet-client"]="apiserver-kubelet-client.key:ca.crt:ca.key"
    )

    for COMMON_NAME in "${!map[@]}"; do
        IFS=":" read -r KEY_NAME CA_CERT CA_KEY <<< "${map[$COMMON_NAME]}"
        
        openssl11 req -new -key "$KEY_NAME" -out "$COMMON_NAME.csr" -subj "/CN=$COMMON_NAME"
        openssl11 x509 -req -in "$COMMON_NAME.csr" -CA "$CA_CERT" -CAkey "$CA_KEY" -CAcreateserial -out "${COMMON_NAME}_new.crt" -days $days
        mv "$COMMON_NAME.crt" "${COMMON_NAME}_old.crt"
        mv "${COMMON_NAME}_new.crt" "$COMMON_NAME.crt"
    done

    cd "$base_path/etcd"
    COMMON_NAME="kube-etcd-healthcheck-client"
    openssl11 req -new -key healthcheck-client.key -out healthcheck-client.csr -subj "/O=system:masters/CN=$COMMON_NAME"
    openssl11 x509 -req -in healthcheck-client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out healthcheck-client_new.crt -days $days
    mv healthcheck-client.crt healthcheck-client_old.crt
    mv healthcheck-client_new.crt healthcheck-client.crt

    COMMON_NAME="$node_name"
    for cert_name in peer server; do
        openssl11 req -new -key "$cert_name.key" -out "$cert_name.csr" -subj "/CN=$COMMON_NAME" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost, DNS:$node_name, IP:192.168.49.2, IP:127.0.0.1, IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
        openssl11 x509 -req -in "$cert_name.csr" -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out "${cert_name}_new.crt" -days $days -extensions SAN -extfile <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost, DNS:$node_name, IP:192.168.49.2, IP:127.0.0.1, IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")
        mv "$cert_name.crt" "${cert_name}_old.crt"
        mv "${cert_name}_new.crt" "$cert_name.crt"
    done
}

extend_certificate "/var/lib/docker/volumes/sf-node-1/_data/lib/minikube/certs" "$NODE_NAME"
extend_certificate "/var/lib/docker/volumes/sfdev-node-1/_data/lib/minikube/certs" "$DEV_NODE_NAME"
```

Which causes new RBAC errors such as, these are not present if I do not touch the certs:

```bash
++ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
++ grep -oP '^ingress-nginx-.*controller\b'
++ awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
error: error upgrading connection: unable to upgrade connection: Forbidden (user=apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

As you can see here the certificates do seem to be correct:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx xxxxxx]$ kubeadm certs check-expiration --cert-dir /var/lib/docker/volumes/sf-node-1/_data/lib/minikube/certs
CERTIFICATE                         EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
!MISSING! admin.conf                                                                                 
apiserver                           Aug 19, 2033 14:21 UTC   9y              ca                      no      
apiserver-etcd-client               Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              etcd-ca                 no      
apiserver-kubelet-client            Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              ca                      no      
!MISSING! controller-manager.conf                                                                    
etcd-healthcheck-client             Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              etcd-ca                 no      
etcd-peer                           Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              etcd-ca                 no      
etcd-server                         Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              etcd-ca                 no      
front-proxy-client                  Aug 18, 2033 14:25 UTC   9y              front-proxy-ca          no      
!MISSING! scheduler.conf                                                                             

CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
ca                      Aug 19, 2033 14:21 UTC   9y              no      
etcd-ca                 Aug 19, 2033 14:21 UTC   9y              no      
front-proxy-ca          Aug 19, 2033 14:21 UTC   9y              no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking to extend minikubes certs in this way, note that the extend function was missing an organisation for the two apiserver certs.

The correct version is:

```bash
extend_certificate() {
    local base_path="$1"
    local node_name="$2"
    local days=3649
    cd "$base_path"

    # Map of COMMON_NAME to "KEY_NAME:CA_CERT:CA_KEY"
    declare -A map=(
        ["kube-apiserver-etcd-client"]="apiserver-etcd-client.key:etcd/ca.crt:etcd/ca.key"
        ["kube-apiserver-kubelet-client"]="apiserver-kubelet-client.key:ca.crt:ca.key"
    )

    for COMMON_NAME in "${!map[@]}"; do
        IFS=":" read -r KEY_NAME CA_CERT CA_KEY <<< "${map[$COMMON_NAME]}"
        
        openssl11 req -new -key "$KEY_NAME" -out "$KEY_NAME.csr" -subj "/O=system:masters/CN=$COMMON_NAME"
        openssl11 x509 -req -in "$KEY_NAME.csr" -CA "$CA_CERT" -CAkey "$CA_KEY" -CAcreateserial -out "${KEY_NAME}_new.crt" -days $days
        mv "$KEY_NAME.crt" "${KEY_NAME}_old.crt"
        mv "${KEY_NAME}_new.crt" "$KEY_NAME.crt"
    done

    COMMON_NAME="front-proxy-client"
    openssl11 req -new -key front-proxy-client.key -out front-proxy-client.csr -subj "/CN=$COMMON_NAME"
    openssl11 x509 -req -in front-proxy-client.csr -CA front-proxy-ca.crt -CAkey front-proxy-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out front-proxy-client_new.crt -days $days
    mv front-proxy-client.crt front-proxy-client_old.crt
    mv front-proxy-client_new.crt front-proxy-client.crt

    cd "$base_path/etcd"
    COMMON_NAME="kube-etcd-healthcheck-client"
    openssl11 req -new -key healthcheck-client.key -out healthcheck-client.csr -subj "/O=system:masters/CN=$COMMON_NAME"
    openssl11 x509 -req -in healthcheck-client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out healthcheck-client_new.crt -days $days
    mv healthcheck-client.crt healthcheck-client_old.crt
    mv healthcheck-client_new.crt healthcheck-client.crt

    COMMON_NAME="$node_name"
    for cert_name in peer server; do
        openssl11 req -new -key "$cert_name.key" -out "$cert_name.csr" -subj "/CN=$COMMON_NAME" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost, DNS:$node_name, IP:192.168.49.2, IP:127.0.0.1, IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
        openssl11 x509 -req -in "$cert_name.csr" -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out "${cert_name}_new.crt" -days $days -extensions SAN -extfile <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost, DNS:$node_name, IP:192.168.49.2, IP:127.0.0.1, IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")
        mv "$cert_name.crt" "${cert_name}_old.crt"
        mv "${cert_name}_new.crt" "$cert_name.crt"
    done
}
```